# Delete last letter of each word if it's letter "s"

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

As indicated in the title, I have a sentence with some words and I want to delete last letter if it is letter `s` for each word of the sentence.

I try this

```
preg_replace("%s(?!.*s.*)%", "", $mystring);
```

But it delete last word only

Comment: Could you elaborate "if it is letter "s" for each word of the sentence"?

Comment: what is the word ends with an s and not just the plural version of a word.  Meaning not ducks (obviously more than one), but a word like gas.  If you are doing this because of plurality, if you remove the s in gas it would be ga and if you remove the s in gases it would be gase.  I think if this is the case you should create a safe word list.  You would ignore those words when doing the test.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `"s\\b"` as regular expression

**Example**:

```
preg_replace("/s\b/", "", $mystring);
```

`s` is your letter and `\b` means a word-boundary.

Answer (score 1):

I think I wouldn't even use regexp to do so.

```
$output = array();

foreach( explode( ' ', $myString ) as $word )
{
    $output[] = rtrim( $word, 's' );
}

$myString = implode( ' ', $output );
```

http://php.net/rtrim

Comment: `$myString = "Wins.";` should return `Win.`.

Comment: Oh, why? Regexes are greate for this kind of tedious work and keep the code very expressive if you supply a comment! :D

Comment: Solutions like this are pretty much the reason why Regexes are awesome - this will have to first split it into words, then trim every word, and then implode it all again (and it's more difficult to understand what it does, if you look quickly). At the same time, this is different from the regex (`s\b`); if the word was "snakesss". The regex would turn it into "snakess" and this would turn it into "snake".

Comment: @Áxel Maybe I just didn't read the question carefully enough…